# Does CMLE provides a REST API endpoint for Prediction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Is there a way I can access a REST API endpoint for a Model created by Cloud ML Engine? I only see:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction $JOB_NAME \
    --model census \
    --version v1 \
    --data-format TEXT \
    --region $REGION \
    --runtime-version 1.10 \
    --input-paths gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/testdata/prediction/census.json \
    --output-path $GCS_JOB_DIR/predictions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact their are two APIs available to do this.

1. The [projects.predict call](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict) is the simplest method. You pass in a [request as described here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request), and it returns with the result. This cannot take input from GCS like your gsutil command.
2. The [projects.jobs.create call](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/create) with the [predictionInput and predictionOutput fields](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#resource-job) allows batch prediction, with input from GCS.

   The equivalent for your command is:

   ```
   POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID/jobs

   {
     "jobId" : "$JOB_NAME",
     "predictionInput": {
       "dataFormat": "TEXT",
       "inputPaths": "gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/testdata/prediction/census.json",
       "region": "REGION",
       "runtimeVersion": "1.10",
       "modelName": "projects/$PROJECT_ID/models/census"
     },
     "predictionOutput": {
       "outputPath": "$GCS_JOB_DIR/predictions"
     }
   }
   ```

   This returns immediately. use [projects.jobs.get](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs/get) to check for success/failure.